# How to cause update of another component?

Tags: angular

After deleting the record, I need to update the data from another component. How, after deleting an entry, reference the operation `this.load()`, which is located in another component?

```
  delete(contact: Contact) {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmComponent, {
      data: {
        title: "Confirm Deletion",
        message: `Are you sure you want a deleted recording?`
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this._contactService.delete(contact.contact_id).subscribe(
          response => this._toast.success(response.message),
          error => {
            this._toast.error(error.error.message);
          },
          () => {
            this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
          }
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What is the structure of your components? Can your component that has to reload receive the emit action from the delete component?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction?

Answer (score 0):

please share more details,
as which component you are using to show update,

else, use service to store update at db and retrieve same update using service in another component in oninit.